# Uploadify - How to send file size using scriptData

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I need to send file name and file size using uploadify. **I DO NOT want to upload the file itself but only send file name and file size.** I noticed that uploadify sends file name by default but does not send file size.I experimented using scriptData but it does not work. Here is my code:

```
$('#logical_item_upload').uploadify({
    uploader        : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    cancelImg       : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    multi           : true,
    auto            : true,
    script          : "<%=save_upload_logical_items_path%>",
    onComplete      : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) { 
        var dat = eval('(' + response + ')');
        $.getScript(dat.upload);},
    scriptData : {
        '_http_accept': 'application/javascript',
        'format' : 'json',
        '_method': 'post',
        'user_id' : '<%= current_user.id %>'
        }
        });
```

I need something like following:

```
scriptData : {
    '_http_accept': 'application/javascript',
    'format' : 'json',
    '_method': 'post',
    'user_id' : '<%= current_user.id %>',
    'file_size': file_size
    }
```

**How can I send just the file name and file size without uploading the file?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [formData](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/formdata/) instead of scriptData? I don't think you can get uploadify to skip passing along the file too (it is a file uploader, after all), but the data you want will still get passed to the server.

As for getting the file size, I don't think there's any way to access it client-side, but on the back end it can be easily accessed with `params[:upload].size`.

Answer (score 0):

The size and filename go up to the server as part of the from/header data. The file size is also buried away in a `file` object attached to each upload queue entry's `.data()`.

You could abort/cancel the upload on the server side, but that seems messy.

Why not just sent a json string of all the files and lengths to another server handler instead of the file receiving one? You can extract it from the 'file' objects in the upload queue.